# Как правильно написать "20 летний"?

Tags: орфография, числительные, сложные-прилагательные, наращение

Нужен ли дефис или наращение окончаний? Обязательно использование цифр!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Сложные прилагательные**, в первой части которых имеются числительные, пишутся слитно. Большинство таких прилагательных образуется от формы родительного падежа количественных числительных:

трёхкопеечный, пятидесятирублёвый, **двадцатилетний**, семисотлетний, двадцатидвухкилометровый, трёхсотсемидесятисемилитровый.
(Сто и девяносто выступают в форме именительного падежа: столетний, девяностодвухлетний.)

Сложные прилагательные можно записать и в **словесно-цифровой форме** (цифрой и присоединяемым дефисом прилагательным).
При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенные наращения после числительных не пишутся:

восьмидесятипятилетний / 85-летний;
**двадцатилетний / 20-летний.**

[**Прилагательное, начинающееся числом**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)