# Как правильно: шестидесяти или шестьюдесятью летней матерью?

Tags: орфография, склонение, падежи, числительные, сложные-прилагательные

Предложение из книги: "Вообразим себя шестидесяти летней еврейской матерью из рабочей семьи Франции". Разве тут не творительный падеж?

Comment: «шестидесяти летней» — в два слова??? «Летней еврейской матерью?»

Comment: @Уроборос Подобный вопрос был недавно: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435084/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-20-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9.  P.S. Хотелось бы посмотреть на эту книгу.

Comment: Это моя ошибка, там шестидесяти-_летней_, последняя часть перенесена на следующую строку, а я тире это не заметил.

Comment: Не тире, а дефис. Это разные вещи. Дефис ставят в этом случае, только когда число записано цифрами: либо "60-летняя", либо "шестидесятилетняя". Впрочем, в ответе Риммы по ссылке выше всё есть. Да ещё и другую ссылку она приводит в этом своём ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***шестидесятилетней*** (слитно).

Подобные слова, даже образованные от трёхзначных чисел, пишутся слитно. Например, *стодвадцатилетие, двухсотсорокапятиметровый.*

Не *шестьюдесятьюлетней* потому, что числительное не склоняется вместе с частью *летний*, а относится к ней: *шестидесятилетняя женщина = женщина шестидесяти лет* (а не "шестьюдесятью лет", что странно звучит).

Answer (score 2):

> Предложение из книги:  "Вообразим себя шестидесяти летней..."
>
> Разве тут не творительный падеж?

Творительный.  Но нужно   слитное написание:

*Вообразим себя **шестидесятилетней**...*

Comment: Предложение из книги: "Вообразим себя шестидесяти летней..." Это не всё предложение. Получается — к а к о й, а не кем?